# Capistrano deploy failed when db:migrate runs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, deployment, capistrano, puma

I'm making a deploy using capistrano but the database is created, the repo is cloned, the release is created but when i run the migrations this error below occurred.

Any help would be great because i'm trying to fix this error for 3 days. I attached config/deploy.rb, Gemfile and Capifile

log/capistrano.log

"INFO [3e233a88] Running /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle exec rake db:migrate as my_app_name@104.236.239.24
 DEBUG [3e233a88] Command: cd /home/my_app_name/apps/my_app_name/releases/20171125031326 && ( export RAILS_ENV="production" ; /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle exec rake db:migrate )
DEBUG [3e233a88]   rake aborted! 
DEBUG [3e233a88]   TypeError: can't dup NilClass
/home/my_app_name/apps/my_app_name/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/redis-activesupport-5.0.4/lib/active_support/cache/redis_store.rb:46:in `dup'
/home/my_app_name/apps/my_app_name/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/redis-activesupport-5.0.4/lib/active_support/cache/redis_store.rb:46:in`map'"

Gemfile
.
.
.

```
group :development do
    gem "listen", ">= 3.0.5", "< 3.2"
     # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
     gem "spring"
     gem "spring-watcher-listen", "~> 2.0.0"
     # Gem Capistrano for deployment
     gem 'capistrano',         require: false
     gem 'capistrano-rvm',     require: false
     gem 'capistrano-rails',   require: false
     gem 'capistrano-bundler', require: false
     gem 'capistrano3-puma',   require: false
 end
```

Capifile

```
# Load DSL and Setup Up Stages
 require 'capistrano/setup'
 require 'capistrano/deploy'

 require 'capistrano/rails/migrations'
 require 'capistrano/bundler'
 require 'capistrano/rvm'
 require 'capistrano/puma'

 require "capistrano/scm/git"
 install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Git

 install_plugin Capistrano::Puma

 # Loads custom tasks from `lib/capistrano/tasks' if you have any defined.
 Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake').each { |r| import r }
```

config/deploy.rb

```
server '104.236.239.24', user: 'deploy', roles: %w{app db web}

set :repo_url,        "https://XXXXXX:xxxxx@github.com/my-account-example/my-repo.git"
set :application,     "my_app_name"
set :user,            'deploy'
set :puma_threads,    [4, 16]
set :puma_workers,    0

# Don't change these unless you know what you're doing
set :pty,             true
set :use_sudo,        false
set :stage,           :production
set :deploy_via,      :remote_cache
set :deploy_to,       "/home/#{fetch(:user)}/apps/#{fetch(:application)}"
set :puma_bind,       "unix://#{shared_path}/tmp/sockets/#{fetch(:application)}-puma.sock"
set :puma_state,      "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.state"
set :puma_pid,        "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.pid"
set :puma_access_log, "#{release_path}/log/puma.error.log"
set :puma_error_log,  "#{release_path}/log/puma.access.log"
set :ssh_options,     { 
  forward_agent: true, 
  user: fetch(:user), 
  keys: %w(~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub), 
  port: 8022 
}
set :puma_preload_app, true
set :puma_worker_timeout, nil
set :puma_init_active_record, true  # Change to false when not using ActiveRecord

set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml}

namespace :puma do
  desc 'Create Directories for Puma Pids and Socket'
  task :make_dirs do
    on roles(:app) do
      execute "mkdir #{shared_path}/tmp/sockets -p"
      execute "mkdir #{shared_path}/tmp/pids -p"
    end
  end

  before :start, :make_dirs
end

namespace :deploy do
  desc 'Upload YAML files.'
  task :upload_yml do
    on roles(:app) do
      execute "mkdir #{shared_path}/config -p"
      upload! StringIO.new(File.read("config/database.yml")), "#{shared_path}/config/database.yml"
      upload! StringIO.new(File.read("config/secrets.yml")), "#{shared_path}/config/secrets.yml"
      upload!(".env.#{fetch(:stage)}", "#{deploy_to}/shared/.env")
    end
  end

  # desc "Make sure local git is in sync with remote."
  # task :check_revision do
  #   on roles(:app) do
  #     unless `git rev-parse HEAD` == `git rev-parse origin/master`
  #       puts "WARNING: HEAD is not the same as origin/master"
  #       puts "Run `git push` to sync changes."
  #       exit
  #     end
  #   end
  # end

  desc 'Initial Deploy'
  task :initial do
    on roles(:app) do
      before 'deploy:restart', 'puma:start'
      invoke 'deploy'
    end
  end

  before :starting,     :upload_yml
  # before :starting,     :check_revision
  after  :finishing,    :cleanup
end

## Database tasks:
namespace :database do
  desc "Create database"
  task :create do
    on roles(:app) do
      within release_path do
        with rails_env: "#{fetch(:stage)}" do
          execute :rake, "db:create"
        end
      end
    end
  end

  desc "Invoke the db migration using the correct stage"
  task :migrate do
    on roles(:app) do
      within release_path do
        with rails_env: "#{fetch(:stage)}" do
          execute :rake, "db:migrate"
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

before "database:migrate", "database:create"
```

Comment: Did you install redis on your server?

Comment: Yes, i also installed redis-server